# Info on Play Store Alpha Testing

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application published on Play Store currently in closed Alpha testing. What happens if I move to production? Users in closed testing group gets the production version? If app in production has an upper version than alpha testing version, they get the upper one? If the production version has a price, they gets upgrades for free?

Answer (score 1):

> I have an application published on Play Store currently in closed
>   Alpha testing. What happens if I move to production?

*If you move from `Alpha Testing` to `Production`, there is no change applied to your package (`versionCode, packageName, etc`). You only make it visible to other users.*

> Users in closed testing group gets the production version?

*They already have the app installed on their device, so as the `version and package name` remains same they wont get any update. They already have the `production version`*

> If app in production has an upper version than alpha testing version,
>   they get the upper one?

*If the `Production` has an `Upper Version,` they are notified about an update.*

> If the production version has a price, they gets upgrades for free?

*NO*